# How do I make my script do something when it's killed by the user?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want my python script to do something when it's killed by the user.
I tried using atexit, but it didn't work.
Sorry for my bad English and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX based systems (OS X, Linux) You can catch a user SIGINT (when they press ctrl-c) and SIGTERM with the following code:

```
import signal
import sys

def signal_term_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'got SIGTERM/SIGINT'
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_term_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_term_handler)
```

On Windows you should be able to do

```
signal.signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, signal_term_handler)
signal.signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, signal_term_handler)
```

Note that by design there are some signals you cannot catch (SIGKILL on POSIX systems) - this is to protect the OS from misbehaving programs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install a [signal handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html).  The specific signals you want to handle depend on what OS you're running on: Windows uses a different set of signals than *nix/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

```
import atexit

def sayHelloWorld():
    print("Hello, World!")


atexit.register(sayHelloWorld)
```

atexit does work, you just have to use it right. Head over to https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html for more information about it